Is it possible to restrict access to URLs in a Tomcat behind a reverse proxy using a `RemoteAddrValve`
I am running Tomcat 9 behind Apache Httpd in a classic setup using mod_proxy
Apache Httpd is configured to act as reverse proxy:
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>      

   # Explicitly do not proxy the error pages

   ProxyPass        "/http_error/" !

   # Hand every request to Tomcat listening on 127.0.0.1:8080 otherwise

   ProxyPass        "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
   ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"

</IfModule>

I can add access control based on IP address at the Apache Http level easily enough using mod_authz_core and mod_authz_host.
But can I do it on the level of Tomcat?
For example, the default manager application performs filtering in its META-INF/context.xml (in my case, /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml) by configuring a RemoteAddressValve:
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
       allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />

The above makes sure that only the manager application can only be accessed by clients coming from the localhost address. In the case of a Tomcat sitting behing a proxy, this is of course always true - all the requests come from 127.0.0.1.
So I thought I might be able to restrict access to host 192.168.1.34 (for example) by doing the following:
Make the IP address of the client examinable
Set up a RemoteIpValve to transfer X-Forwarded-For headers into the requests' originating IP address field:
In server.xml, at the Engine level:
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
       internalProxies="192\.168\.1\.30|127\.0\.0\.\1" />

where internalProxies list the expected address of the reverse proxy.
Filter by IP address
Change the RemoteAddressValve entry in the webapp's context.xml to:
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
       allow="192\.168\.1\.34" />

We should now be able to access the webapp from a client with IP address 192.168.1.34.
That trick does not work - access from 192.168.1.34 is actually rejected!
So maybe the configuration is the correct one. From the manual:

usePeerAddress: Use the connection peer address instead of the client IP address. They will differ, if a reverse proxy is used in front of Tomcat in combination with either the AJP protocol, or the HTTP protocol plus the RemoteIp(Valve|Filter).

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
       usePeerAddress="true"
       allow="192\.168\.1\.34" />

But that doesn't work either, access is not permitted either.
Is it possible to get this to work?
